# How to view history of data/apps I sent using Wi-Fi direct to another phone?

Tags: wifi-direct, file-sharing

I am using Android 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean) on one of my phones. I want to see apps/files/data I sent to another phone using Wi-Fi direct.

I did a bit of research on this topic, but I found no answer to this question. I cannot find any option. I even searched "Files" but there was no option related to sending files/apps via Wi-Fi direct.

Is it possible to see apps/files/data I sent through Wi-Fi direct?

Answer (score -1):

I recomend you to try SilFer. SilFer can transfer files using Hotspot, WiFi, WiFi-Direct. The app is available for Android, Linux,Mac and Windows.

Download the app on Google Play:

SilFer File Transfer - Android Apps on Google Play

Comment: I do not want any app right now. I just want to see my history of files and apps that are transfered using Wi-Fi Direct.